# Will my biometric passport still work if I don't have any data stored on the chip?

Tags: visas, passports

I got a biometric passport and due to system failure at a time I was told that my Consulate wasn't able to put data on the chip. (No data at all) I need to travel to France with school for 3 weeks and French consulate said that if I have a biometric passport I don't need Schengen visa to enter. I told both Ukrainian and French Consulates that I have biometric passport but there's no data stored on it and both said: " It's still a biometric passport." Does anyone know how it works and will I have any problem with the border control because of the missing data on the chip? I'd think my passport would count as invalid for visa-free entry. Does anyone know anything about this? Please advise.

Comment: It's hard to know.  The country that issued it is relevant here.  There would be a greater suspicion of it being a counterfeit passport, which could slow border formalities for you.

Comment: The one thing we can be sure of is that you won’t be able to go through the French e-passport gates. Beyond that... be sure to provide for some buffer in you schedule just in case...

Answer (score 5):

[You might also find this question relevant](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1901/what-happens-if-rfid-system-in-my-biometric-travel-passport-malfunctions-when) as your case is not much different from a failed chip.

In my opinion you should have no issues, especially considering the French consulate confirmed it. The **document** you are being issued is indeed "biometric passport" (Ukraine doesn't issue any other type of passport for over a year now) and thus you satisfy [the requirements](http://europa.eu/rapid/press-release_STATEMENT-17-1270_en.htm).

Thinking about it, except very few people who bothered with NFC readers, nobody has any idea whether their passport chip contains any data. I have UA and US passports myself, and have no idea whether their chips contain anything, as I never bothered to check.

Comment: There are several Android apps which will read biometric passports.  I don't know of any iOS apps though.

Comment: NFC seem to be more locked down on iOS. But case in point, I have an NFC android phone and know about those apps, and still never tried to read any of my passports.